# k8s deployment imagePullPolicy set to ifNotPresent still pulls images

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Hello all I am trying to figure out what is making our GCP k8s pull images even with the image has been set as a specific version and the policy is `ifnotpresent`. Is there a way to check the image age inside the cluster? Anyone has any idea what might cause this. By documentation if the policy is `notpresent` and the image doesn't have tag latest it should pull it only once. What happened is that one of the images that we use, the image repo went down for some reason which caused `imagepullbackoff`, the cluster is running fine for the past year and a half, suddenly the repo drops and we got a problem. I know that one of the solutions is to use our own image registry but still, wondering why is this happening.

Comment: It might be landing on nodes where the image is not previously cached?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or you are just curious? You are referring to the Kubernetes cluster created via `GCE` and `Kubeadm` or you are referring to `GKE`? Also this image you are asking was publicly like in dockerhub or it was your own personalized image and it was in your `Artifact Registry/Container Registry`?

Answer (score 0):

With current information it is hard to indicate any particular reason.

Depends if you are using `Google Kubernetes Engine` or `Google Compute Engine` with `Kubeadm`. If you have configured [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry), [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry) or you are downloading images from [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/)

In general, you are right about the `IfNotPresent` policy. In [Understanding Kubernetes Image Pull Policies](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/11463/understanding-kubernetes-image-pull-policies/) blog, you can find default behavior:

> You don’t have to specify an image pull policy. When a Pod lacks a policy, Kubernetes will infer your intentions from the image’s tag. If you’ve supplied a specific tag (such as my-image:my-release), **the image will only be pulled if the tag doesn’t already exist on the Kubelet node.** This policy is called IfNotPresent.

Similar information can be found in the [Openshift Image pull policy overview](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/openshift_images/managing_images/image-pull-policy.html#images-image-pull-policy-overview_image-pull-policy):

> IfNotPresent - Only pull the image **if it does not already exist on the node.**

In short, if you have some autoscaler which creates a node and image is huge, it will need to download it to that node.

You have also mention:

> What happened is that one of the images that we use, the image repo went down for some reason which caused imagepullbackoff

This behavior might be related with the way how the image was pushed, like in [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview#registries)

**Useful links:**

- [Pulling cached Docker Hub images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pulling-cached-images)
- [Preparing a Google Kubernetes Engine environment for production](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/prep-kubernetes-engine-for-prod)
- [Deploying to Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/integrate-gke)

**To sum up**

It's hard to determine the exact reason why GCP behaved like this with current information. Logs, and more details of behavior and env configuration would be required. Only things which comes to my mind is that there was a new node which required to download this new image or reuploading this image to Artifact/Container registry changed some background values (some kind of ID).